# How do I make certain endpoints of the woocommerce rest api authless?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

The Woocommerce rest API requires authentication through a consumer key and a consumer secret to access any of its endpoints. I'm currently building a store frontend using Nuxt js and Vue and I really want to use the Woocoomerce API as a backend restful API to power my store - (get products, categories and the like).

Unfortunately I can't simply pass the consumer key and secret through my frontend to access woocommerce as it will give the frontend client full control over woocommerce so anyone who opens devtools and checks the secret and key can call wocommerce on sensitive endpoints I didn't intend it for.

There is a plugin called [Public Woo API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/public-woo-api/) solves some of this problem but doesn't work for all endpoint I need (most expecially order). The only obvious solution I can think of is a way to remove authentication for some endpoints.

How do I even do that? I don't even know where to begin. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can utilize Netlify Functions https://www.netlify.com/products/functions/

Comment: Wow. Just looked at the docs and it's really cool. I was infact planning to create a nodejs backend just to handle those endpoints I needed if I couldn't get it done in woocommerce. But the only caveat is that you have an extra layer in the system which can mean slower response time. Or would it matter really? Thanks. This is a definitely valid option.

Comment: Coming back to this. Netlify functions would have been a nice choice to use but there's a caveat. The free types only run for a maximum of 10 secs. And wordpress it turns out can be slow atimes. So while I managed to make it work atimes, I was on the edge (7 - 9 secs) most times and it was just impractical to to rely on such a system. The background fucntions on netlify which can run longer are paid and that was just a no-brainer for me.