# How to get only product list from WooCommerce API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get all WooCommerce products list from API to my Vue-script. For common WP API I used code:

```
fetchPosts: function(){
                  var url = 'https://some-example-website.org/wp-json/wp/v2/post';
                  fetch(url).then((response)=>{
                    return response.json()
                    }).then((data)=>{
                      this.posts = data;                      
                    });
                },
```

and got posts objects array from JSON, and did all I need with it.
I'm trying to use URL https://some-example-website.org//wp-json/wc/v2/products. But it returns 401 error
Is there some simple way just to get products (all data), without any authorization, any secret keys? Or I should be only authenticated user? Can't find info neither in WC API docs, no another web-resources.

Comment: Woo API needs authentication to be accessed. https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/ . If you want to access without api you can build your own json using sql or query and read from it ?

Comment: @Snuffy thank you so much. Actually I missed your comment so I reached this solution by myself (I know - everybody say so :) ). But I created own "api-page". Just page without any data accept of data-json. Something like that

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65125694/how-do-i-make-certain-endpoints-of-the-woocommerce-rest-api-authless), which indicates that none of the WooCommerce REST endpoints are public, but there may be options to do so.

Comment: Kindly, this should be a comment, not an answer please.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys. Good news - I am not stupid so much, really there is no fast solution. Bad news - all "slow" solutions doesn't work for me. Ok, I can leave with it))

Answer (score 0):

At least (and like some guys advised) I created own "end-point", something like very simple, almost ridiculous API page:

```
<?php
/*
Template name: Product API Page
*/
?>

<?php $query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 0) 
);
?>        
<?php
$temp = '[';
while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post();
global $product;
$temp = $temp . '{"sku":"' . $product->get_sku() . '","titlte":"' . $product->get_title() . '"},';
}
$temp = $temp . ']';
$jsonObj = str_replace(",]", "]", $temp);
echo $jsonObj;
?>
```

Maybe I was wrong. But it works.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. Maybe this solution will be useful for some other cases. But for this case is enough just use common WP API link - https://some-example-website.org/wp-json/wp/v2/product Just simply that :)))))